# while using RTMP Streaming there is lot of burden on my server

Tags: rtmp, live-streaming

1.I have server of my own. Using this server I want to run live streaming program in my server
2.For this I have selected RTMP streaming.
3.For this i have developed a website in which I have used JarisFLVPlayer
4.Till here everything is fine .
5. But thing is if visitors on our site increases, burden on the server is also increasing. Because each and every  request is going to server.
6.Is there any solution to reduce burden on our server 
7. Is there any solution  like  mirrioning ,catche... using in my website

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Either **improve the configuration of the server** (I hope you know the game. More the users , Higher must be server's performance . hence you need to upgrade) or **Go for [RTMFP](http://www.adobe.com/in/products/adobe-media-server-extended/rtmfp-faq.html)**.

Comment: Thanku @sh4nx0r But can you please tell me how to use RTMFP